# Confusion on how Covariant Derivatives work on Vector fields

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I'm currently watching these [Lectures on General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEaiZBbCVtI&t=5556s&ab_channel=TheWE-HeraeusInternationalWinterSchoolonGravityandLight) and I tried to work out a simple example to help me understand the content of the lectures better. I tried to calculate the acceleration of a particle moving in a uniform circular motion, but using the "new" formalism introduced in the lectures.

I choose my manifold $\mathcal{M}$ to be $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I define the curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ where:

\begin{equation}
\gamma(\lambda)=(\cos\lambda,\sin\lambda)
\end{equation}

My Chart is Simply $x^1(a^1,a^2)=a^1$ and $x^2(a^1,a^2)=a^2$. The first thing I do is calculate the velocity, in the way defined in the lectures. According to the lectures the tangent vectors are maps of the form:
\begin{equation}
v_{\gamma, p}=\dot{\gamma}_{x}^{i}(\lambda) \cdot\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right)_{p}
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation}
\dot{\gamma}_{x}^{i}(\lambda)=\left(x^{i} \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right)_{p}(f)=\left.\partial_{i}\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)\right|_{x(p)}
\end{equation}
Where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ is a basis vector and $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a scalar function. Note that this far in the lectures that are vectors are defined only as maps that act on these kinds of scalar functions.
Therefore my vector field is the following:
\begin{equation}
X=-\sin\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}+\cos\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}
\end{equation}
Where $X^i=\left(x^{i} \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}$ this is a function from $X^i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and this is what confuses me. Later in the lecture he generalizes the covariant derivative to vector fields (at minute $32$).I apply this to my vector field and I get the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_{X} X &=\nabla_{X^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}} \left(X^{j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right) \\
&=X^{i} \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}}\left(X^{j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right) \\
&=X^{i}\left(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}} X^{j}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}+X^{i} X^{j}\left(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)\\
&=X^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\left( X^j \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}+X^{i} X^{j}\left(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The first derivative on the right hand side according to the definition earlier is this:
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right)_{p}(X^j)=\left.\partial_{i}\left(X^j \circ x^{-1}\right)\right|_{x(p)}
\end{equation}
This expression makes no sense to me because the maps don't fit, $x^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ and $X^i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Can someone help me find where I'm making the mistake here?

Comment: I think the confusion comes from this: The expression $-\sin\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}+\cos\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}$ is the tangent vector to the curve at the point $\gamma(\lambda)$. This is not a vector field. A vector field is $X^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}$ where each $X^j$ is a scalar function on the whole of ${\cal M}$.

Comment: But how can someone speak of the velocity field at the whole of $\mathcal{M}$? Shouldn't that mean that the particle has a velocity even at points it never reached?

Comment: What you say about that particle is not even conceivable. A velocity field on the whole of ${\cal M}$ is equivalent to an ordinary first order differential equation $\dot y=f(y)$ where $f:{\cal M}\to\mathbb R^n$. A *particular* solution of this ODE depends on an initial condition $y_0=\gamma(0)$ and is the trajectory of a particle that has velocity $\dot \gamma(\lambda)$ at point $\gamma(\lambda)$. That curve does in general not reach all points of ${\cal M}$ *but* the velocity field, aka ODE, is defined on the whole of ${\cal M}$.

Comment: But shouldn't it be possible to calculate the velocity field just by knowing the parametrized curve of the particle? How do you extend the velocity field to the whole manifold?

Comment: You can't. Knowing a particular solution of an unknown ODE does not allow you to deduce what that ODE is (has not even anything to do with manifolds). Again: parametrized curve has tangent *vectors* . ODE "is" the velocity field. The latter contains more information.

Comment: BTW . I found it very pleasant to learn this stuff from Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry lecture notes which appeared as book also in print with more material in it.

Comment: Apart from all this: has my remark that $X^j$ is *not* a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ (as you wrote) helped to solve the confusion ? $X^j$ is a function ${\cal M}\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, this comment helped a lot, sadly it created a new confusion. Now I don't understand the definition of acceleration  If the acceleration is defined as $\nabla_{v_{\gamma}} v_{\gamma}$, I don't see how you can take the derivative of this.  At some point it has to include a term of the form $\frac{\partial \dot{\gamma}^{n}}{\partial x^{m}}$ where $\dot{\gamma}_{x}^{i}(\lambda):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Note that in lecture 8 minute $34:29$ of the series he mentions this as "strictly speaking not defined" but during his explanation, I still don't see how you can make sense of it.

Comment: I have no incentive to watch that youtube video. Look for a better source that's not confusing you. I believe you should also go through [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/691577/304394).

Comment: I think I understand what you did in your post. You assumed there is a Velocity field that coincides with the tangent vectors at the world line of the particle and this allowed you to take the derivative then. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: . Yes. Correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me!